# Duck and Go disturbing image output

Tags: duckduckgo

Look it does advertise itself as not tracking user's historical selections, and so this is a **rational paranoid feeling** to think that it knows my sexual preference. Well in terms of gender anyway.

[image]

Other explanations?

Comment: Websites and webapps belong on [webapps.se] but this is more of a misunderstanding that certain phrases have different meanings based on context per the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pin out is to fasten a paper pattern to material before cutting.

[Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) says
**"Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity."**

Pick a better search engine.

<sup>BTW, Google does the same thing, but they start further down the page</sup>

Comment: Well ok it's not like I actually care I mean my data is only going to be a statisticians worst nightmare I can only assume but scepticism of text based statements should not be attributed to suspicion of malice Sir

Comment: Sir or Madam, my entity placeholders are not gender specific

Comment: If you attribute paranoia, you imply malice; if it's not malicious, why be paranoid about it?… which is beside the point. That's the wording of Hanlon's razor, unadulterated.

Comment: I'm not disputing the  truth value of your initial statement, but this one I do. Paranoia is simply scepticism that is yet to be refined into a conclusion with vagaries still flawing any assertion, malice cannot be implied by it, it isn't a directive towards any specific entity

Comment: It's not like I have a detailed knowledge of every individual that is involved with the software I use, mate, come on if malice was what I sought to prove I've chosen a very obscure way to go about it for the past few decades

Comment: I have sporadic and or no control over my maturity levels, especially in text based interaction. This is a key note of the presentation I think.